# 404 error when I click a link while I'm under a tag page

Tags: wordpress

first of all sorry for my English.

And my problem is: If I'm on a "tag" page and click a link which refers to another page in my site I got 404 error. Links are working when I'm in category page or main page.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a live URL you can show us?

Comment: Sure! http://blog.ajuans.com/tag/grafik-tasarim/
When you click on the "kullanici sozlesmesi" link on the footer you can't reach. But this problem only occurs in under "tag" permalink

Comment: Any ideas about this situation?

Comment: for me this link is working http://blog.ajuans.com/kullanici-sozlesmesi/ so what is an issue ? can u pls elaborate ?

Comment: No, I wanted to say that it's not working when you click it while you are on a "tag" page. I mean permalinks which wordpress created.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted in your footer isn't properly formed to resolve correctly. The href in that link is simply `href="kullanici-sozlesmesi"`, with no url before it.

Changing that footer link to `href="http://blog.ajuans.com/tag/kullanici-sozlesmesi"` should fix the problem

Comment: But the footer link is correct, that "tag" section created by wordpress and if you enter a "tag" section link does not working, but in the main page it works correctly.

Comment: The problem is that the footer link is wrong. It's URL in the code is "kullanici-sozlesmesi". That's not a URL, it's just the slug of a tag! Your browser assumes you meant for it to be a relative URL (like "/home"), and just appends it to the end of whatever the CURRENT url is. Sometimes that works (depending on the current page), sometimes it doesn't. And WordPress even sometimes tries to step in and *guess* what you mean, and redirects to similar content. Bottom line, change the URL in your footer link to my answer above, and it will work on every single page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I can explain the situation like this;

wordpress gives an extra label to the link at the footer which is "/tag", how can I disable this I don't know...

I'm telling again, it's only a problem when I click that link while I'm under the "/tag"